# Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.importing strapi sdk

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, strapi

Hi I am trying to import javascript strapi sdk ([link)](https://medium.com/strapi/announcing-the-strapi-javascript-sdk-ac89f140a9d1) in my new project which is configured using web pack 
Here is my code yet

***index.ts file***

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import  Strapi from 'strapi-sdk-javascript'

const strapi = new Strapi('http://localhost:1337')
```

here is my ***webpack.config.file***

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.ts',
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: 
            {loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['env']
            }
        },
      //  include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app")],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
        $: "jquery/src/jquery",
    }
},

devtool: 'inline-source-map',
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/assets/template.html'
    })
],
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
 };
```

and this is giving my this error 
[image: error]

what am i doing wrong here . please
 help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
// Process JS with Babel.
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
  include: [path.resolve(__dirname,"./src/app")path.resolve('node_modules/strapi-sdk-javascript')],
  loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
 },
```